# Doctrine createQuery() conditional params

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I am trying to put a conditional parameter in my query.  if orgID is null i do not want the query to use it as a filter.

```
 AND (:orgID IS NULL OR o.id = :orgID)
```

I am struggling trying to do this. What am i doing wrong?

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
$query = $em->createQuery('
    select count(d.id) 
    from \***\OrganizationBundle\Entity\Organization o 
    inner join \***\OrganizationBundle\Entity\Facility f
    inner join \***\OrganizationBundle\Entity\Department d  
    where d.active = true
    AND f.active = true
    AND o.active = true
    AND d.name LIKE :name
    AND (:orgID IS NULL OR o.id = :orgID)                
');
$query->setParameter(':name', '%' . $name . '%');
$query->setParameter(':orgID', $orgID);
$count = $query->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Comment: What is wrong? What error do you get?

Comment: You making it too difficult.  Check orgID and simply don't add it to your query if null.  A simple andWhere is all you need.

Comment: This is, by the way, a good use case where the Doctrine `QueryBuilder` class comes in handy instead of manually writing the query in DQL.

Answer (score 1):

Both `@Cerad` and `@xabbuh` from comment section are right. Either skip appending the predicate or use `QueryBuilder` to conditionally make your query string.

In any case, remember that prepared statements placeholders cannot be used for table names and columns.

Also, from performance standpoint, you need not to run a query if you know for a fact that it will return previously known results. That's just waste of resources.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with what others have said - use `QueryBuilder` as this is the Symfony / Doctrine way.

But if you want to solve it on the MySQL query level, then you will need something like "conditional `WHERE` clause", for example using [`CASE` expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case).
Replace

```sql
AND (:orgID IS NULL OR o.id = :orgID)
```

with

```sql
AND
    CASE
        WHEN :orgID IS NULL THEN TRUE
        ELSE o.id = :orgID
    END
```

The first condition explicitly evaluates to TRUE, which is essentially equal to your requirement: "I do not want the query to use it as a filter". (Although technically this is still a filter).